# Web API Not Returning data using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am newish to JQuery Ajax.

My code below always return the error function. Am I doing something wrong? I can see the json data in the response header using firebug I can't get the success function to work.

```
var url = "http://ec.europa.eu/budg/inforeuro/api/public/monthly-rates"

$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Ajax Error Occurred");
    }
});
```

Comment: well, if you look at the actual error returned it might give you a clue...what error is returned by the server? You can either look in the Network tab of your browser dev tools, or you can handle the error callback of the $.ajax method properly (see api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the source you're using the JSONP request on actually supports JSONP?

When calling the url http://ec.europa.eu/budg/inforeuro/api/public/monthly-rates?callback=foo (note the callback param) the response from the server does not contain a valid JSONP response (which would contain a call to the `foo` function).

Comment: No I'm sure it definitely does. The webservice docs are basic. If I just try to use json I get the  'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. Any suggestions for another way to try?

Comment: I meant I'm not sure if it does.